# SQL Pivot table for each hour

Tags: sql, pivot

I have table as below

```
Prefix scandate
A      1/2/2013 08:30
A      1/2/2013 08:45
B      1/2/2103 09:15
```

I need output with count in every hour i,e

```
Time             A          B
08:30-09:30      2          0
09:30-10-30      0          1
```

Till 7PM

Can some one help me

Comment: I just answered this for oracle and days >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534615/creating-date-variable-to-get-multiple-counts-of-a-given-variable/16534656#16534656

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what DB you are using, something like this should works:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(m, 30, scandate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As '00:30 - 01:30 Block'
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(m, 30, scandate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As '01:30 - 02:30 Block'
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(m, 30, scandate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As '02:30 - 03:30 Block'
...
FROM table
```

You'll just need to iterate out the hour part identifiers until 7 PM i.e. 1, 2,...19.  Caveat, this won't work for any times before 12:30 AM.

Comment: Mistakenly used COUNT instead of SUM.  Perchance Hogan you could provide an improved answer?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do like this:

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(
  HOUR(SUBTIME(scandate, '00:30:00')), ':30', 
  '-',
  HOUR(ADDTIME(scandate, '00:30:00')), ':30') AS time, 
 SUM(IF(prefix = 'A', 1, 0)) AS A, 
 SUM(IF(prefix = 'B', 1, 0)) AS B 
FROM tableName 
WHERE TIME(scandate) <= '19:00:00' 
GROUP BY HOUR(SUBTIME(scandate, '00:30:00'));
```

Notes:

- the query MUST HAVE these **sub** and **add** times, so intervals like `08:30-09:30` will change to `08:00-09:00` and will have a common hour (except for the exactly 09:00, which the hour is 09, instead of 08).
- I tried only datetime functions to reach the expected value to `time` column in the output, but I could only reach it with `CONCAT`.
- If you have other values to the column `prefix` (others than 'A' and 'B'), you must improve the query adding more `SUM(IF(prefix = 'A', 1, 0)) AS A`, changing the character and column alias to the expected value.

Hope it works for you!

**EDIT**

Based on @bluefeet comment, you can change this query according to your RDBMS with the exact commands that reach the same results as:

- `CONCAT`: concatenate two or more strings;
- `HOUR`: extract the "hour" part from a datetime (or a time);
- `TIME`: extract the "time" part from a datetime;
- `SUBTIME`: subtract two times;
- `ADDTIME`: sum (add) two times;

`SUM` and `IF` are expected to work the same way in almost all RDBMS, as well as the basic structure of the query (`SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`).